# create card box with twitter-bootstrap and animate.css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, animate.css

I try create a card with bootstrap+animate.css

**PLEASE check with google chorme last version:**

```
    <div class="shop-card well">
        <h3><a href="/">title 1</a></h3>
        <a href="/">
           <figure class="figure">
               <img class="figure-img img-fluid img-rounded" src="http://wewswiderska.home.pl/images/3dspace.html-i1.png">
           </figure></a>

           <div class="price">1234 <span class="symbol">R</span>
                 <del>5678</del>
           </div>

          <form class="hide buys" id="inform-ordering-5" name="inform-ordering-5" role="form" style="overflow: hidden;position: absolute;left:-1px;width: 100%; bottom: -1px;">
               <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" data-target="#phoneModal" data-toggle="modal" href="#">modal</a>
               </div>
          </form>
     </div>
```

I want When I move my mouse over the card, A red button appears. And then disappear.

ّI done it.

ّNow when I click on the button, It opens a modal box.

I done it!

But this is my problem:

when I close the modal box, contaners of card floats to left!

here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1pyeg7w2/

I couldn't solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped your `div.shop-card.well` content with another div with `position:relative` rule and it seems to be working

```
<div class="shop-card well">
    <div style="position:relative">
        your content here
    </div>
</div>
```